# How to pause and resume with option to keep tracking in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm struggling to analyze my code computation wise. The main function runs nested loops in some sort of complicated way and I'm searching for the values that takes too long to calculate so that I can figure out a special case for them.

This ties up to my original question in the title. Let's say there is a loop that sums numbers from `1 to 10^20` (just hypothetical), how can (if possible at all) pause operation at will and get output on screen about current progress and time elapsed. Later on continue with the computation if needed without losing progress.

I think it could be useful tool in cases you aim for certain precision when you don't know how to estimate the time it will take to compute. Or just in general for long computations if so needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is called debugging and can be used from Juno, more info can be found here: http://docs.junolab.org/latest/man/debugging/

Other useful option include:

1. `Logging` module
2. `@show`, `@debug` macros to show the variable, state etc
3. `serialize` function to store the state of your variables (and perhaps resume later)

Last but not least, if you do not want to use IDE there is a `Debugger.jl` (https://github.com/JuliaDebug/Debugger.jl) package. Here is a sample usage:

```
using Debugger

function foo(n)
    x = n+1
    ((BigInt[1 1; 1 0])^x)[2,1]
end

@enter foo(20)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm having trouble using serialize, can you perhaps edit your answer with a simple example?

Comment: Here is a minimal example: `using Serialization;x=5; open("data.jld","w") do f;serialize(f,x);end` There are many scenarios and approaches available here. This makes good start: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Serialization/  However, if you still have problems just ask a SO question :-)